# How to dump the GPT under Ubuntu Lucid?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, dump

Is there a tool on Ubuntu Lucid which can dump the GPT (GUID partition table) of a block device in a human-readable form? The most important information I'm interested in is the byte offset of each partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the answers to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/154076 as inspiration.

Recent `sudo fdisk -l`, `sudo gdisk -l DEVICE` and `sudo parted -l` dump the partition table of `DEVICE` or all block devices, and all of them support (and autodetect) MBR and GPT. However, they don't display the byte offsets directly. They do display the unit (logical sector size) they use though, which is 512 bytes by default.

Answer (score 1):

`parted` should be able to [`print`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html#print) the table, and will give you starting and ending of each partition, but I'm not sure that GPT uses byte offsets.  [`gdisk`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/walkthrough.html) gives its offsets in sectors, you'd multiply sectors by Logical Sector Size to figure out # of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking that you probably want to read this:
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html

Answer (score 0):

To dump raw bytes :

```
xxd /dev/sdx | more
```

replace `x` in `sdx` with your gpt device character
`more` is used to prevent data flowing without control on terminal.

happy hacking :)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. The output of this command doesn't contain the byte offset of each paritition (directly), which was specified as a requirement in the question.